# How to make Gui do the calculations whle inputing variables into JTextField? how to make a popup box appear when JCheckBox is chosen

Tags: java, user-interface

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JPasswordField;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.awt.event.ItemListener;
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.FocusListener;
import java.awt.event.FocusEvent;

public class Gui extends JFrame {

    static JTextField text;
    static JTextField text2;
    static JTextField text3;
    static JCheckBox tsp;
    static JCheckBox tbsp;
    static JCheckBox cup;
    static JCheckBox pint;
    static JCheckBox quart;
    static JCheckBox liter;
    static JCheckBox gallon;
    static JCheckBox oz;
    static String unit;
    static int conv;

    public Gui(){
        super("My title");
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        final JTextField text0 = new JTextField("Enter the unit you are using at the moment         (Tsp, Tbsp, Cup, Pint, Quart, Liter, Gallon, Ounce)");
        text0.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){

            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){
                text0.setText("");
            }
        });
        add(text0);
        unit = text0.getText();
        ///////////////////////////UNIT\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\

        final JTextField text = new JTextField(
                "Enter the amount you have ( Must be a number.)",20);
        text.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){

            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){
                text.setText("");
            }
        });
        add(text);
        String str = text.getText();

        try     {
            conv = Integer.parseInt(str); 
            ///////////////AMOUNT TO CONVERT\\\\\\\\\\\
        }
        catch(NumberFormatException e){
        }

        text2=new JTextField("Which unit do you want to use:",20);
        text2.setEditable(false);
        add(text2);

        //text3=new JTextField("You need "+conv+"",20);
        text3.setEditable(false);
        add(text3);

        tsp = new JCheckBox("Tsp");
        tbsp = new JCheckBox("Tbsp");
        cup = new JCheckBox("Cup");
        pint = new JCheckBox("Pint");
        quart = new JCheckBox("Quart");
        liter = new JCheckBox("Liter");
        gallon = new JCheckBox("Gallon");
        oz = new JCheckBox("Ounce");
        add(tsp);
        add(tbsp);
        add(cup);
        add(pint);
        add(quart);
        add(liter);
        add(gallon);
        add(oz);

        HaandlerClass handler = new HaandlerClass();

        tsp.addItemListener(handler);
        tbsp.addItemListener(handler);
        cup.addItemListener(handler);
        pint.addItemListener(handler);
        quart.addItemListener(handler);
        liter.addItemListener(handler);
        gallon.addItemListener(handler);
        oz.addItemListener(handler);

        HaandlerClaass actionListener = new HaandlerClaass();

        tsp.addActionListener(actionListener);
        tbsp.addActionListener(actionListener);
        cup.addActionListener(actionListener);
        pint.addActionListener(actionListener);
        quart.addActionListener(actionListener);
        liter.addActionListener(actionListener);
        gallon.addActionListener(actionListener);
        oz.addActionListener(actionListener);
    }

    private class HaandlerClaass implements ActionListener{
        public JTextField text3;
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {

            if(tsp.isSelected())
            {text3.setVisible(true);}
            if(tbsp.isSelected())
            {text3.setVisible(true);}
            if(cup.isSelected())
            {text3.setVisible(true);}
            if(pint.isSelected())
            {text3.setVisible(true);}
            if(quart.isSelected())
            {text3.setVisible(true);}
            if(liter.isSelected())
            {text3.setVisible(true);}
            if(gallon.isSelected())
            {text3.setVisible(true);}
            if(oz.isSelected())
            {text3.setVisible(true);}
        }
    }
}
```

It is supposed to have the calculation pop up when the chack box is selected.

I'm making a recipe calculator, where I want to multiply a recipe by however many times it needs to be multiplied, say a recipe when done serves 4 people and she has a party and needs to feed 20 people, so it would be the recipe times 5, but she doesnt want to use 8 cups so she'll put the info in the calculator and it will change it to 4 pints, or however many liters or gallons...etc. I editede all of the conversions out, so now thats left is just the action and command code

Comment: I would suggest making a minimal example and edit your post. That way you are going for sure to be helped.

Comment: by minimal example you mean showing what it does so far, or what it's supposed to do?

Comment: I mean writing the minimum program that you can, which can reproduce what you want/asking, so that people can take a look in not so many lines of code as you have posted.

Comment: Look at [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Ok I removed the unnecessary conversions, now it should be better to help find the problem.